# How can I use gMaps with Angular2 ? Is that possible?

Tags: google-maps, angular

I need to create typeahead service for cities and so on. 
At the same time I need to use a typeahead directive (ng2-bootstrap), so I just need an array of strings which I'll be given by my service.

I decided to use google maps for that.

This code was taken from an example of google maps api

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
  {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
```

I need to use it with Angular2... how can I do that? And is it possible?

Thank you in advance and good luck!

Comment: This is very broad. It's likely possible, but try to break down the job to more specific questions

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have edited my question a little bit. For example: I'm typing "Alabama" in my input, I begin with "Al" and then I get the results which I can choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set an object from the callback associated with your event. Here is a sample:

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
  this.selectedPlace = autocomplete.getPlace();
});
```

and bind the form against this object

```
<form>
  Name: <input [(ngModel)]="selectedPlace.name"/>
  (...)
</form>
```

**Edit**

You need to reference an element to apply on using the `ViewChild` decorator:

```
<div #autocomplete></div>
```

and in the component:

```
@ViewChild('autocomplete')
autocompleteElt:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.initAutocomplete();
}

initAutocomplete() {
  this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    this.autocompleteElt.nativeElement,
    {types: ['geocode']});
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about this line "new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
  {types: ['geocode']}); "... How can I create that Autocomplete object?
Thank you for your answer =)